# Hard time understanding execution of machine instructions

Tags: cpu, instructions

Im reading the book "Write great code: understanding the machine" by Randall Hyde, is a great and clear text but here im completely stuck with his explanation of, for example, the mov instruction.

He dissects the steps for the `mov(srcReg,destMem)` instruction as follows:

```
1. Fetch the instruction's opcode from memory.
2. Update the EIP register with the address of the byte following the opcode.
3. Decode the instruction's opcode to see what instruction it specifies.
4. Fetch the displacement associated with the memory operand from the memory location immediately
following the opcode.
5. Update EIP to point at the first byte beyond the operand that follows the opcode.
6. If the mov instruction uses a complex addressing mode (for example, the indexed addressing mode),compute the effective address of the destination memory location.
7. Fetch the data from srcReg.
8. Store the fetched value into the destination memory location.
```

Im lost in steps 4-6. My exact questions are:

Step 4: Why do I need this displacement, how Im gonna use it later and why?

Step5: I understand that in step 2, the EIP must "point" to the next byte where the next instruction to be executed is stored. But I dont understand why does EIP needs to be one byte beyond the operand address. I belived that EIP was concerned only with instructions/opcodes, not data.

Step6: What is exactly and effective address? Are there other types of address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Step 4:

Some opcodes reference memory that's relative to the opcode's location. For example, a function might have a constant or static piece of data. If it does, the code may opt to place that right before the function starts (or right after it ends) and refer to it by saying "get the memory from 46 bytes earlier". That's the displacement -- it's an offset from the contents of a register (in this case, EIP), used for referencing data relative to the register's contents.

## Step 5

The operands for opcodes are normally stored right after the opcode. So you might have some memory arranged like so: `a b c`. `a` is and opcode, `b` is the operand for `a` and `c` is the next opcode.

If you only move EIP to the end of `a` (so it references `b`), then in the next instruction cycle, the computer will assume that `b` is the next opcode to execute. `b` isn't supposed to be an opcode though; it's an operand. The computer can't tell the difference between an opcode and an operand though. It just assumes whatever EIP points to is an instruction and executes it. That's why EIP needs to be moved past the operand too.

## Step 6

An "effective" address is just an absolute one (relative to the start of memory) while the "complex" address the book refers to is relative to something else (often the contents of a register).

Step 4 showed that an opcode might not refer to an absolute memory address. It could easily refer to a relative one. In fact, programs very frequently refer to addresses that are relative to some register. For example, if you wrote `some_struct.data` in C and compiled it for an x86 processor, it would load the address of `some_struct` into a register (say, EAX), then hard-code `data`'s offset from the base of `some_struct` into the operand. So if there are 5 bytes of data between the start of the struct and the start of the `data` element, then the instruction might look like `load [EAX + 5] -> EBX` which means "take what's in EAX, add 5, fetch the data from that address and put it in EBX".

The thing is, the memory doesn't really understand relative addresses like this. It only understands absolute ones. So in order to access a relative address, the processor has to first add that 5 to whatever's in EAX to compute an absolute address. Then it can send that address to the memory controller and have it understood.

There are two basic types of relative addresses I've worked with (there are more I haven't).

- Register relative: The processor takes the contents of a register and uses that as the address in memory. Depending on the opcode and processor support, it may also add an operand to the register as well. Step 4 was dealing with this kind of addressing, with EIP as the register the address was relative to.
- Memory relative: Sometimes referred to as "indirect". The processor starts out with a register relative address, then automatically fetches the data at that address and treats it as the real address.
- Wikipedia describes lots of other addressing modes on their [addressing modes](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Addressing_mode) page.

Memory relative took me a while to understand. Say you did a memory relative load where the register contains `10` and the offset is `5`. The processor will add them together (`10 + 5 = 15`). Then, it'll go to that address (`15` in this case) and grab whatever's there. If address `15` happens to contain the value `60`, then `60` will be treated as the actual address and the processor will load the contents of address `60`. If you're familiar with a language with pointers (e.g. C), memory relative is like a pointer-to-a-pointer.

Comment: What you call "indirect" is usually termed "memory indirect" to distinguish it from "register indirect" (which is effectively just base plus offset with a zero offset and sometimes encoded as such). [Wikipedia's article on addressing modes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addressing_mode) provides more information.

Comment: I prefer the term `relative` over `indirect` since `indirect` doesn't seem very intuitive (maybe it makes more sense if you're an expert). I like your point about `memory relative` (indirect) though. It has a nice symmetry with `register relative` that seems a little more intuitive and easier to grasp. I edited my answer to use that. Thanks for the tip!